# How to change the status of a Context.sublime-menu item on Sublime Text?

Tags: contextmenu, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I've wrote a plugin with a context menu which changes by the situation, does exists some way to do that?

```
plugin_menu = sublime.load_settings('Context.sublime-menu')
children = plugin_menu.get('children')
children[0]["caption"] = "Message changed"
plugin_menu.set('children', children)
sublime.save_settings('Context.sublime-menu')
```

I've tried with `load_settings` which loads it correctly but it doesn't save it, basically because it is not the right way to do it and `load_settings` probably should be used for `.sublime-settings` files.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a command for each action, but you may be able to leverage the `is_visible` method. Here is an example of it's usage.

```
class AdvancedNewFileAtCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, dirs):
        if len(dirs) != 1:
            return
        path = dirs[0]
        self.window.run_command("advanced_new_file", {"initial_path": path + os.sep})


    def is_visible(self, dirs):
        settings = sublime.load_settings("AdvancedNewFile.sublime-settings")
        return settings.get("show_sidebar_menu", False) and len(dirs) == 1
```

I check for a setting and the number of directories specified. This particular example is used to selectively display a Side Bar context menu.